# Scheduled task not able to write files on an external server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I'm having problems with a scheduled task running in a windows 2003 server scheduled task

Task is running under the nt authority/system account sending files to another windows2003 server in same domain.

Machine where task is executed runs under a domain account with limited permissions in domain and machine

Folder where files are sent in remote server has been configurated granting total rights to system and user which

The problem happens when scheduled task  is tying to write the file in remote server, task returns an exception like "Access denied to path ...."

Which is the user which remote server detects running externat scheduled task?
Which permissions should i grant in remote folder?

Thanks in advance

Fernando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Scheduled Task running as the System user will not have access to another machine on the network. When it runs it is the same as if you were to logon to the local machine instead of the network. You will need to run the task as a special network user or store the file on the machine running the task for another process to pick up later.

Comment: Right, so simply open the scheduled task, and change the user/pass to a domain account that has permission to write to that remote box.  Should work fine.

Comment: Thanks both, the problem is that this process also requires special permissions and we tried to find an easy solution running it under system account, i'll create a special user.

Answer (score 0):

A process run under Local System account doesn't have permissions to access other computers' resources. A typical solution is to create a separate domain user exactly for running the tasks and run the task under this user.

Comment: Thanks a lot sharptooth you and john had confirmed me that we needed an special user account.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mentioned solution of creating a domain user to run under, if you just need anonymous network access or "domain member" network access, you can also run as `Network Service` which as a positive side has almost no rights on the local computer (unlike `Local System` which is even more powerful than `Administrator`).